# vlc player recorded live stream with m3u8 url and using this video at html5 player

Tags: video, stream, html5-video, vlc, codec

I recorded live stream on VLC player with this code;

```
vlc  http://sourceaddress.m3u8 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=C:\\\\Users\\\\mypc\\\\Desktop\\\\%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%.mp4,no-overwrite}} --run-time=100 vlc://quit
```

So,I try to play the video on HTML5 video player.
But no sound on video,Also i uploaded to vimeo, it works fine!

I think that codec problem but i never find a solution

Checked with mediainfo;

> General 
>   Format : MPEG-4 
>   Format profile : Base Media 
>   Codec ID : isom (mp41/avc1) 
>   File size : 14.9 MiB 
>   Duration : 57 s 22 ms 
>   Overall bit rate : 2 187 kb/s 
>   Writing application : vlc 2.2.6 stream output
>
> Video 
>   Format : AVC 
>   Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
>   Format profile : High@L3.1 
>   Format settings, CABAC : Yes 
>   Format settings, ReFrames : 4 frames 
>   Codec ID : avc1 
>   Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding 
>   Duration : 56 s 760 ms 
>   Bit rate : 2 062 kb/s 
>   Width : 1 280 pixels 
>   Height : 738 pixels 
>   Original height : 720 pixels 
>   Display aspect ratio : 1.734 
>   Original display aspect ratio : 16:9 
>   Frame rate mode : Constant 
>   Frame rate : 25.000 FPS 
>   Color space : YUV 
>   Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
>   Bit depth : 8 bits 
>   Scan type : Progressive 
>   Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.087 
>   Stream size : 14.0 MiB (94%)
>
> Audio 
>   Format : MPEG Audio 
>   Format version : Version 1 
>   Format profile : Layer 2 
>   Codec ID : 6B 
>   Duration : 57 s 22 ms 
>   Bit rate mode : Constant 
>   Bit rate : 128 kb/s 
>   Channel(s) : 2 channels 
>   Sampling rate : 44.1 kHz 
>   Compression mode : Lossy 
>   Stream size : 888 KiB (6%)

Comment: Download `MediaInfo` and check your file with it. What does it say about video codec? Vimeo re-encodes input videos, they don't direct-copy the bytes.

Comment: PS: Whats this `acodec=mpga`? for MPEG's MP4 the audio codec must be MPEG too (either AAC or MP3).

Comment: @VC.One mpga=mpeg audio

Comment: @VC.One edited post

Comment: When recording use `acodec=mp4a` this will give you the AAC audio that's expected in MP4 files by browser decoders. Open the file in VLC to see if you can re-encode from `mpga` to `aac`. I'm more familiar with FFmpeg commands than VLC but ideally you want to "copy" the video track since that's fine and only encode the audio track. In FFmpeg that would be `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy output.mp4` if that helps...